# Python Hangman Output

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, func, function

When I try running the program the output when asked "So far you have guessed" the output is not on the same line as the prompt rather on the line below it.Any way to fix this? Also are there any other faults within the program that should be fixed?

```
HANGMANPICS = [''' ''', ''' 


    |   




 ''', '''


    |   
    0   



 ''', '''


    |   
    0   
    |   


 ''', '''


    |   
    0   
   /|   


 ''', '''


    |   
    0   
   /|\  


 ''', '''


    |   
    0   
   /|\  
   /    

 ''', '''


    |   
    0   
   /|\  
   / \  

''']

def getSecret_Word(): 
while True:
    wordList =input('Please enter a word to be guessed\nthat does not contain ? or white space: ')
    wordList = wordList.strip()
    if ' ' and '?' not in wordList: #makes sure that the word is valid
        break
return wordList #returns back to wordList if invalid

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
print()
blanks = '?' * len(secretWord)

for i in range(len(secretWord)): 
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

for letter in blanks: 
    print(letter, end='')
  print()


print('So far you have guessed:', ', '.join(sorted(missedLetters+correctLetters)))
print()



def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
  while True:
    guess = input()
    guess = guess.lower()
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print('You can only guess a single character.')
    elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
        print('Please enter your next guess:\nYou have already guessed the character:',guess)
    elif guess.isspace():
            print('You must enter a guess.')
    else:
        return guess

def playAgain():
  print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getSecret_Word()
gameIsDone = False

while not gameIsDone:
  displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

if guess in secretWord:
    correctLetters = correctLetters + guess


    foundAllLetters = True
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
            foundAllLetters = False
            break
    if foundAllLetters:
        print('You correctly guessed the secret word: ', secretWord)
        gameIsDone = True
else:
    missedLetters = missedLetters + guess


    if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
        print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
        print('You failed to guess the secret word:',secretWord)
        gameIsDone = True


if gameIsDone:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit the line break after a `print` statement, just use `print("string", end="")`

Comment: Thank you. Any other problems in the program?

Comment: @DatOneGuy  "Thank you. Any other problems in the program?" I think you got the wrong impression of this site. It was built to answer specific questions, not to look through your code for you. Sometimes you may get tips but you cant come asking for this or your question can get closed